# parsing file ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have a file with data like this:

```
01 JUL something
       something
       something              445
       something else
01 JUL whatever
       everwa3
       lklkj                  445
       something else
02 JUL ljkjlkj
       ljkljlkj 
       lkjkjlk                500
       lkjkj
02 JUL ljlkjklj
       lkjkjlkj
       lkjkj                  500
       lkjlkj
```

In the end I would like to find out how many occurences of 
01 JUL 445 there are and 02 JUL 500 there are

in this case it would be..

```
01 JUL 445 = 2

02 JUL 500 = 2
```

I am able to read in lines and get the data out ...how can I go about counting the same things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counts = {}
date = ""
file.readlines.each_with_index do |l, i|
  if i % 4 == 0 # first line
    date = l.split("\t").first
  elsif i % 4 == 3 # third line
    wierd_num = l.split("\t").last
    counts[date+" "+wierd_num] ||= 0
    counts[date+" "+wierd_num] += 1
  end
end

puts counts # => {"01 JUL 445" => 2, "02 JUL 500" => 2}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Though, now I am having trouble with UTF-8 characters. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897398/broken-utf-8-string-ruby