# broken UTF-8 String ruby

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, character-encoding

While reading a file I get `broken UTF-8 String error` whenever I have the following in my file

`través`

if I change it to normal `e` then it works.

Whats the way to fix this?

error only happens if I do `line.lstrp` or any other function.  Just printing the lines is ok.

problem even happens when I try to match the string with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your file is not UTF-8 encoded. So, you should either take care of that (save your file using UTF-8), or tell Ruby that your strings aren't going to be UTF-8. In order to do that, you can either

- use `-E encoding` command line switch for that
- pass `-E encoding` using `RUBYOPT` environment variable
- specify encoding within Ruby comment
- do `force_encoding` method on already loaded string before operation such as `lstrp`

There's a lot of Ruby encoding-related reading on following blog:

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/understanding_m17n